# Mongodb query hanging system

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am using MongoDB version 2.6.

I have around 3 million data in it. **When I am firing this below query it's hanging my whole Java application.**

(I am using `Mongodb connector` to retrieve data from there.)

```
db.collection_name.find{
    "client_id.event.currentDate": {
        $gte: "2016-12-18",
        $lte: "2017-01-17"
    },
     "client_id.event.name": "SEARCH HOTELS SUCCESS",
    _id: {
        $lt: ObjectId('5856428ce4b0f530cc74c090')
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to retrieve this type of large data?

**Edit** 1:

**we have an index on my collection**

```
{"client_id.event.name" : 1 ,"_id" :1 ,"client_id.event.currentDate" :1}
```

**Edit 2:**

Sample document from database:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57a316a60cf26576defb7837"),
        "client_id" : {
                "clientIp" : "50.23.117.45",
                "event" : {
                        "installationId" : "us2zv39vti5v",
                        "action" : "END",
                        "client_us_lastCommunicatedAt" : "2016-08-01T10:23:38.502Z",
                        "duration" : 60,
                        "client_us_userUpdatedOn" : null,
                        "name" : "APPSESSION",
                        "appId" : 3,
                        "userName" : "us2zv39vti5v",
                        "currentDate" : "2016-08-01T10:24:38.502Z",
                        "superProperties" : {
                                "client_us_installAt" : "2016-08-01T10:23:38.502Z",
                                "client_us_cookieEnabled" : true,
                                "client_us_referrer" : "Self",
                                "client_us_screen_width" : 768,
                                "client_us_counter" : 1,
                                "client_us_screen_height" : 1360,
                                "client_us_brand" : "Google",
                                "client_us_browser_version" : "23.32.12.20",
                                "client_us_screen_dpi" : 96,
                                "client_us_os" : "Windows",
                                "client_us_screen_colourDepth" : 24,
                                "client_us_os_version" : "10",
                                "client_us_flashVersion" : "no check",
                                "client_us_lastCommunicatedAt" : "2016-08-01T10:23:38.502Z",
                                "browser" : "Chrome",
                                "client_us_screen_pixelDepth" : 0,
                                "client_us_referring_domain" : "Self",
                                "client_us_css_pixel" : 1,
                                "client_us_mobile" : false
                        },
                        "userProperties" : {
                                "duration" : 60,
                                "Country" : "IN"
                        },
                        "installProperties" : {
                                "email" : "us2zv39vti5v@gmail.com"
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the embedded field names in quotes, as in `"client_id.event.currentDate"`?

Comment: edited, please have a look again.
I missed double quote here in question but in real query its there.

Comment: You need to investigate what's hanging. Usually, it's the query execution which is running on your MongoDB instance and not the data loading from MongoDB. Working with large data sets is done best by using streaming.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a couple of documents from that collection so that we can see the document schema? This will specifically answer the question on what the data type of the field `"client_id.event.currentDate"` is...

Comment: could you please have a look at the question again.

I have index my database as updated in the question

Comment: @chridam datatype of `"client_id.event.currentDate"` is String

Comment: Can't you just update your question with some sample documents from your collection? Is `"client_id.event"` an embedded document or an array?

Comment: @chridam please have a look. Updated my question with sample document from database

Comment: Thanks for the update, from the looks of it, `currentDate` is not a string but an `ISODate` where its value is the string representation of the date. Try changing your query to use a date wrapper, e.g. `"client_id.event.currentDate": {
        $gte: new Date("2016-12-18"),
        $lte: new Date("2017-01-17")
    }, ... `

Comment: @chridam When I used date wrapper in spark mongo query I got the following error
 
`config.set("mongo.input.query",
“{"client_id.event.currentDate
":{$gt: new Date("2016-12-18"), $lt:new Date("2016-12-28")},"client_id.event.name
":"LOGIN"}”)`
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided JSON String is not representable/parseable as a DBObject`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 millions data, and each of them have at least 4 fields of Date . 
Now when spring-mongo-data requests all this from mongo it has to transform the String value of date (which is kind of json string date format = Java String ) into java Date object for 12 millions of dates. So it will take a while.